# Strange behaviour with StdIn.readLine in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I came across some strange behaviors of StdIn.readLine in Scala. Here's the code excerpt:

```
while (true) {
  print("prompt:>")
  var lbl = ""
  lbl = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  println("echo" + lbl)
}
```

Strangely, when running, the readLine() happens before printing out the "prompt:>".

I have:

```
fork in run := true
connectInput in run := true
```

in my build.sbt

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Did you put those two lines in build.sbt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is line buffered. You need to `System.out.flush` after printing the prompt to make it show up in the console. Otherwise, it waits for the buffer to fill (or a new line to appear in the output).

Answer (score 1):

Writing to files (and the terminal is considered one) is costly, so for performance reasons the standard output is buffered. This means that the write will actually only occur once the buffer becomes full, or once a line return gets put into the buffer. You can force the buffer to flush using `System.out.flush`.

For your problem however, you might want to use `scala.io.StdIn.readLine("prompt:>")` directly: it's made exactly for what you're trying to do.

Comment: System.out.flush works but readLine(String) doesn't. It's quite strange as it's supposed to work. I think there might be something to do with the fork in run.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when running codes in the console, i.e Ctrl+shift+X on a piece of code in IntelliJ to have them run in the console. I added those line you indicated in the build.sbt and for feeding in the input into the console I use Ctrl+Enter after typing the input. Just for your info, my Scala code is:

```
import scala.io.StdIn.{readLine}
val input = readLine("enter some word ")
println(s"the word is $input ")
```